# how to access data value using LINQ vb2010, i try this code but it fail

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class Form1
  Dim bd As New lDataContext

  Dim qqq = From bs In bd.FILEs
              Select bs.RETURN_DATE
              Take 1

 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If qqq = Date.Today.Date Then
        TextBox1.Text = "yes"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "no"
    End If
 End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
Dim qqq = (from bs in bd.FILEs select bs.RETURN_DATE).First()
```